# Bibliographies at the ends of chapters

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I realize that similar questions have been asked before. I have looked at the threads, and read the `biblatex` documentation. But it hasn't helped.

I have a document for which I'd like to add the bibliography at the end of each chapter, rather than at the end of the document. All my references are in one `.bib` file.

However, using the solutions posted by other users, I have two problems:

1. The bibliography is not printed at the end of each chapter.
2. When the references are cited, instead of numbers, I get the cite-key!

Here is the sample of my code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}    
\usepackage{graphics}    
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}    
\usepackage{moreverb}    
\usepackage{subfigure}   
\usepackage{epsfig}    
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\usepackage{hangcaption}   
\usepackage{txfonts}   
\usepackage{palatino}    
%\usepackage[style=trad-plain,sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}    
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\tolerance=9999 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}    

\begin{document}    
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}   
\begin{refsection}  
stuff....\cite{cite-key}   
\printbibliography[heading={subbibliography}]    
\end{refsection}    
\end{document}
```

I want numbers and not cite-keys for the citation. And I'd like the references printed out at the end of the chapter.

Also, I'm using TeXShop on Mac. I compile the main `.tex` file once, then the `.bib` file using the `bibtex` option in TeXShop, and then compile the `.tex` file at least twice.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You should run `bibtex` on your `.tex` file, non on your `.bib` file. Btw, why are you using `bibtex` and not `biber` with `biblatex`?

Comment: Thanks. I will look at the formatting guidelines. 
I had always used bibtex, but now I changed to biber and it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Btw I see you loaded both `graphicx` and `graphics`: the first is enough. And  you loaded `subfigure` twice: only one is needed.

Comment: subfigure is obsolete for mor than a decafe by the way

Comment: Also, don't load both `txfonts` (which provides a Times Roman font clone) and `palatino` ( which provides a Palatino clone). Load one package or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ops I forgot `subfigure` is obsolete. Kumz: use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs! subfigure, txtfonts were in the template for the thesis given by the university. Being a new user, I was afraid to meddle with it. I will change it now.

Comment: Any news here? Did you get things running in the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: I ended up using biber and it worked.